# Is there a way to get field => value pairs from a subselect in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm considering how to best implement an Audit Trail in an app, which is backed by MySQL. A few systems access the same database and tables, so I thought triggers would be the best solution.

However, I don't want to manually write a trigger for every table, so I'm looking to automatically log the field name and data for each insert/delete.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO `audits` SET
    `table_name` = 'jobs',
    `table_key` = OLD.`id`,
    `changed_at` = NOW(),
    `notes` = (SELECT * FROM NEW);
```

However, the subselect will return a single row result set, which cannot be treated as string. I want a function that will take that row and convert it to:

```
"id = 1, name = 'something', another_field = 'data'"
```

Or something like that.

Edit: The main point here is that I don't want to have to type in every field in every table. There's over 120 tables, and some have > 100 fields. If it's not possible in MySQL itself, I guess I'll write a little program to spin over each table and field and generate the SQL for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually wrote a PHP script to loop over each relevant table and build the triggers for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CONCAT('id = ', id, ', name = ''', name, ''', another_field = ''', data, '''')
FROM    NEW
```

Answer (score 0):

only

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(col1) FROM yourtable

but this return all field by comma delimiter or other separator  that you can declare.

[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the strings.

e.g:

```
select concat("id = ", t.id, "name = ", t.name) from myTable t;
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to have to type in every field in every table. There's over 120 tables, and some have > 100 fields.

If it's not possible, I guess I'll have to write a little program to spin over each table and field and generate the SQL for me.